# VMWare Virtual Machines with shared file system resources

Tags: vmware, samba

I need to share some folders between two different VMWare virtual machines, one running Linux and one running Windows 7.

How I can do that in simple way?

Comment: Where are the shared folders? On the host or the VMs ?

Comment: I need to share folders between two vitual machine.. and also if possibile between a virtual machine and the host...answering to your question on both

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vmware workstation it has a shared folder capabilities if you are running the vmware tools on the guest OSes.

you setup a folder on the host and then the guests can access that folder.

Here is documentation for setting this up in workstation 5. http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html i'm assuming it's similar in later versions.

Comment: I'm not using WMVare workstation but VMServer version

Answer (score 1):

In exactly the same way as if they were real machines.

Samba installed on the Linux VM can share local data through a network link (either a physical one [two bridged networks to the same adaptor] or an internal or host only network). It can also access Windows shares through the same network.

Answer (score 1):

Install Samba on your host (probably preferred) or on the Linux VM (the next best choice), then map a drive letter in Windows to the Samba share.

Samba
  http://www.samba.org/